# Why isn't the slider in my custom UITableViewCell reacting to the drag attempts?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uislider

I'm creating an app in UIKit, programmatically.
One screen has a UITableView with custom cells, some have sliders inside. All cells show up and can be selected. Other custom cell elements like buttons and text field react to interaction, but not the sliders.
Here's my code:

```
class CellWithSliderValues: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider! = {
        let ctrl = UISlider()
//        color setup here
        return ctrl
    }()
    
    // some labels
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(slider); 
        // layout code, skipped for StackOverflow
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

How the cell is created for the table, with tag calculation skipped:

```
let cell = mainScreen.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWithSliderValues") as! CellWithSliderValues
                cell.slider.maximumValue = Constants.BEST
                cell.slider.minimumValue = Constants.WORST
                cell.slider.value = currvalue
                // tag is set here
                cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChange), for: .valueChanged)
                return cell
```

Part of the delegate that is called when clicking of the slider cell:

```
guard let cell = (mainScreen.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CellWithSliderValues) else {return}
            cell.slider.becomeFirstResponder()
            return
```

Finally, the function that should be called when the slider is dragged but is never actually called (seen with breakpoints):

```
@objc func sliderChange(sender: UISlider){
        // get the values here
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

The same approach did work with the text entry fields, so what am i doing wrong here? Is it because of the Slider not having delegates?

Comment: You should be adding the slider to `cell.contentView`, not to the actual cell.

Comment: You have `@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!` ... which indicates you added the slider in your cell prototype in Storyboard. So, you should **not** be creating a new one and adding it to the cell in your code.

Comment: Also... are you trying to create a **single row** with a slider? Or, are you trying to create **multiple rows** each with its own slider?

Comment: Added responces:
I do not use storyboards, my code is purely programmatic.
Yes, I want to create a few different cells, with some, a few of them, having sliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenter Sulthan's solution of adding a slider as a subview to the cell.contentView instead of the the cell directly worked like a charm.

```
self.contentView.addSubview(slider);
```

I wonder why didn't other cell elements require that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).